# Prevent Lookup link to User account from redirecting to useless overview

Tags: lookup, user

We created a lookup to the user account on the contact record as our users also need a contact record.  But when you click that link instead of taking you to

/005xxxxxxxxxxxx

it redirects you to useless page of

/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?u=005xxxxxxxxxxxx

How do we prevent that from happening?